# NetBeans 12.1 freezes for a few minutes when I try to Open a Project

Tags: java, netbeans, freeze, netbeans-12

I've been having this issue for weeks now.
Whenever I try to Open a Project or try to do anything which requires access to my files, it freezes.

I tried all of the following things but to no avail:

1. Downgrading it to 8.2
2. Clearing the cache in my %APPDATA%  folder
3. Deleting all my old projects which might be faulty
4. Re-installing both NetBeans as well as JDK 15.0.1

My Specs are:

- Intel Core i7 - 7700k @ 4.2GHz
- 16.00 GB DDR4 3200 MHz RAM
- Windows 10 Pro Version 1909, OS build 18363.1198, x64

Using JDK 15.0.1